# Microsoft Graph - No mailbox found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have Office365 developer account with a couple of users. I am attempting to access their mail via a daemon app (i.e. headless) using the Microsoft Graph API.

I have verified that mailboxes exist for these users, but I'm getting an error:

```
ErrorNonExistentMailbox
No mailbox was found that includes the specified identity: `xx@yy.onmicrosoft.com`
```

I have previously obtained a token as a registered app (via `apps.dev.microsoft.com`) and included it with the following request URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xx@yy.onmicrosoft.com/messages
```

Any guidance?

The token comes to me in the first operation like this:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3599,
"ext_expires_in": 0,
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEWDhHQ2k2SnM2U0s4MlRzRDJQYjdyblpfdTg3QjlwS2hFeG5ncFRpS1gwczVwY2k1YnpobHZDdTFlVi1uRlFkRk0yMHlJZ1MxdnlBbC1UUnBYdGNoakxIYkhMb21hT28wb3UxaTkxYnJKRENBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiaUJqTDFSY3F6aGl5NGZweEl4ZFpxb2hNMllrIiwia2lkIjoiaUJqTDFSY3F6aGl5NGZweEl4ZFpxb2hNMllrIn0.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.DMpgiNfazeDd2KsEjHAggKAg3STMeK59ls9-whHaf-UEON_fvP45ay6PrqfAnwdqz-QKmX-8ikyiM8zuE5r8IGL1d7zYzJCnIECeQwtg8OKzYJPyDW7V0RAF0yePT2fg22luGhFz5yqzjSGlxhWauZmkmXq7JrGrO7fhzAUwoJh7XJrIOlfj098LPoTrmfAaOn36hBmmcQyuFNDhW5E6oXqZsyssJ5SKvaXN_w62IrXv2-nmIkZwyqcrVlCnX_Q1ytrFuc_xItL0FFe_5MbRiF-JIxdbeFNE8LR06mFWfEGHyJu01SJvgxE9500nVzok94qCX-r5lxN0WqVLOuTqEg"
```

}

Comment: Could you provide an example of the token you're receiving?

Comment: Sure - edited msg to include token response msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong. When requesting the token initially, I was using "common" as the tenant portion of the URL. Apparently, although legal, this does not give the appropriate permissions. The token I got back, when decoded, does not list any permissions, and this would have been a clue if only I had been a little more familiar with the JWT token content and format.

Once I changed the tenant portion of the URL to either the tenant GUID (retrieved from AD), or the fully qualified domain name (something like `yy.onmicrosoft.com` in my case), I got back a different token, one that includes a list of the Microsoft Graph permissions I had granted in the app registration portal.

Using this new token, I was able to retrieve the mail from the mailbox of any user in my domain. Thanks to Marc for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It is likely that you changed something else along the way. You should be able to use `/common` or `/organizations` with the `client_credentials` grant.

Comment: Oh I did get a token back using `/common` but it gave me the error I reported. After getting it working, I went back and changed it back to `/common` and the same error returned, so it was definitely that that made the difference.

When I use the organization id instead, the token contains additional information, including a list of roles/permissions that is not present in the token I get back from the `/common` version of the endpoint.

Comment: And who the heck voted my answer "not useful" when it actually solved the problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem...and i solved it this way. Its strange why /common does not work. I suppose it might be a bug of some sort.

Comment: or could this be because xxx.onmicrosoft.com is a trial/developer account?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify Aldu's answer, I did also have the same issue.

Obtaining the *admin* consent, it is fine to use `/common` as in [step 2 of the instructions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent) .

However, then requesting an access token from the microsoft auth server via `client_credentials` at `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, I found I *needed* to replace tenant with a tenant ID. That changed my access token and allowed access to the resources.